# Adding offset in GET to cron job

Tags: php, optimization, import, cron

I have an importing script written in PHP. This script read quite big txt file and import some data to DB. I would have to know which is the best way to import big set of data without errors.

When I'm trying to run this script in browser, after some time I see too long execution time error even if I set some settings:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
ini_set('memory_limit','2000M');
```

I would have to be albe to run my import script with offset support but I don't know if it will work with CRON.

```
if($line > $offset)
{
    $_GET['offset'] .= 500;
    header("Location: http://www.example.com?offset=$_GET['offset'];
    die;
}
```

Will it work with cron?

Comment: Can you break up the data set and run multiple cron jobs?

Comment: Not really. I have no access to source file nor to cron settings...

Comment: Can we see the database insert script you are using? There may be potential enhancements there that could speed up code execution.

Comment: So looks like there is no way to do this so looks like i have to just optimize it as ssergei implicitly said. Thanks guys.